# Azure apim developer portal - mimic depreciated portal feature

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

Previously in the azure deprecated developer portal there was an “admin functionality”, we need to bring it back to the new self hosted developer portal

> to view all the Clientapp releated to an api

> to view all the clientapp in the developer portal

> to have the “allow tracing” on subscription to get api inspector log

Comment: You can [Access and customize the developer portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-developer-portal-customize) and also [Migrate from deprecated to the new developer portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/developer-portal-deprecated-migration)

Comment: You can open an issue on GitHub: [api-management-developer-portal](https://github.com/Azure/api-management-developer-portal/issues)

Comment: @DeepDave-MT we have migrated this but on the new portal we don t find the admin functionality to see 'Allow tracing' in the api operation details page. This was visible in old depreciated portal .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [azaslonov](https://github.com/azaslonov) and [ErikMogensen](https://github.com/ErikMogensen). Posting your suggestion as an answer to help other community members.

> we have migrated this but on the new portal we don t find the admin functionality to see 'Allow tracing' in the api operation details page. This was visible in old depreciated portal

- We removed the Trace tab from the developer portal altogether. It was a legacy feature available only to the administrators. We recommend using the test console in the Azure portal instead.
- But if your backend service requires an OAuth token you cannot test it from the Azure Portal. When trying this from the developer portal I can as a workaround add a header with Ocp-Apim-Trace: True and use a subscription which allows tracing

You can refer to [Unable to view API-M Trace in new Developer Portal](https://github.com/Azure/api-management-developer-portal/issues/301#issuecomment-553690914) and [Debug your APIs using request tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-api-inspector)